# How to tell AWS MSK connector to start reading messages from timestamp in the past

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I use Terraform to deploy MSK cluster and MSK connector (it converts topic messages into parquet format and sinks them into s3).

My question is, let's say I want to rewind the consumer back to some previous timestamp and start consuming from there. In case of Kinesis streams, we may set the parameter called "initial position" which could be `[TRIM_HORIZON, LATEST, AT_TIMESTAMP]`. I need something equivalent to `AT_TIMESTAMP`, but for Kafka consumer.

For example there's an option `--from-beginning` for Kafka consumer, which is equivalent to `TRIM_HORIZON` for Kinesis. Couldn't find anything for `AT_TIMESTAMP` though.

Is there a way to do that, and if yes then where do we need to specify it in Terraform? Is it a part of MSK connector construct?

Comment: Removed aws tags since answer is generic to kafka connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query a topic's offsets by timestamps, and you would use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` to provide a timestamp to reset a connector's consumer group id to that (after stopped). Then when you resume the connector, it should consume data after that time.

This only applies to sink connectors, not source connectors, which maintain offsets differently per source system (such as file lines, or sequential database ids, etc)

Comment: thanks for reply. yes, of course it's for sink connector, source connector is not a consumer (is it?). I upvoted for now, and once I'm done with the checks and verify that it works, I will come back and mark it as accepted

Comment: MirrorMaker2 is a "source connector" but it reads and also writes to Kafka, so uses both clients

Comment: looks like the group should be inactive in order to update its consumer offset(s), and you mentioned it; otherwise `Error: Assignments can only be reset if the group '...' is inactive, but the current state is Stable.` is shown. but how to make it inactive? does it mean i need to delete the connector, and re-create it every time when i wish to update the offsets? looking at connector's page in AWS console, and CDK/Terraform parameters for it, there's no "active/inactive" toggle

Comment: we are setting `capacity.provisionedCapacity { mcuCount = 1; workerCount = 1; }` in msk connector's terraform construct. probably setting them to 0 would "pause" it - it won't have workers but would still be a part of terraform stack, and when I set them back to 1, it's going to resume execution. will try that.

Comment: The Connect API has a /pause endpoint. I don't think you can trigger that from Terraform. Otherwise, yes, you could set `max.tasks = 0` on the connector config, or scale down the Connect workers as well. Any connector configs would still be in the MSK topics

Comment: another option would be setting `auto.offset.reset` in consumer configs, it does not require updating task/worker counts and eliminates the need to use kafka CLI related to consumer groups, although it is limited to `earliest`,`latest` and `none` only and does not support custom timestamps

Comment: That setting cannot be applied in the connector config without also overriding the group id